# How to change the User password

Tags: password

Alright i go into the terminal and type in

```
sudo passwd random-pass
-enter-
[sudo] password for user:[]
```

I type whatever password i want in and the insertion point/caret just stays in the same spot. I type and it gets all dodgey so it shows nothing when i type my password

```
-enter again- (thinking it is fine when the insertion point isnt moving)
Sorry; try again
[sudo] password for user:
```

It does nothing and i cant process nay commands, well not many throughout the terminal.
It is VERY agitating.

Comment: Sorry i had it organized within the body.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to change your password, open the **About Me** control panel, and click the *Change Password...* button and follow the prompts.

The `sudo passwd random-pass` command you issued actually means switch to the super user (the `sudo` bit), and change the password for the `random-pass` user.  The initial password prompt was from `sudo` and was asking for your current password.  If you entered that in correctly, it would then run the `passwd` command.

If you want to change your own password from the command line, just run `passwd` by itself with no arguments and not via `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

The cursor doesn't move because people aren't supposed to easily see how long the password is. It *is* being stored anyway.